# Transformation Constraint with Animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

Is it possible to do Transformation Constraints with Animation Nodes?
I would like control an object rotation over another object location/translation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.
You can read an object's transform values with the **Object Transforms Input** node and set them on another object with the **Object Transforms Output** node.

If you'd like to read an object's absolute location in world space as it might be the child of some other object, you could use the **Object Matrix Input** node.

[image: Transformation Constraints in Animation Nodes]